# Plotting the instantaneous power of an RLC circuit

Tags: power, oscilloscope, watts, proteus, multisim

So I've been solving some basic instantaneous power/ average power problems and I've been asked to "draw" $$p(t)$$ which is the instantaneous power function of the circuit, I guess there are two ways to accomplish this task:

First, you basically sketch the voltage waveform and the current wave form and keep picking points on both traces and multiplying them (I don't think I'm going to do this)

second, and this is what I actually did, found $$p(t) = \frac{V_mI_m}{2}cos(2\omega t+ϴ_v+ϴ_i) + \text{avgpower}$$

and sketched the graph manually.

**OK my question is** if it's possible to check my answer using any simulation program -multisim maybe- by constructing the circuit and plotting the power waveform just like the oscilloscope plots voltage waveform?

Comment: Sorry didn't get what you mean by the voltage sources allowing angular offset what does this has to do with the power graph?

Comment: I did a little searching on Google, and it does appear that you can plot something on Multisim. However, you will have to use custom formulas. [Check this out](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Multisim-and-Ultiboard/Graphical-Instantaneous-Power/td-p/2937076).... by the way, I deleted my last comment :P

Comment: @KingDuken seems legit, still going to give scilab a try because I'm a "cheap sucker" :D

Comment: LOL okay man, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the average power in a series RLC-circuit we can write:

$$\overline{\text{P}}_{\space\text{in}}:=\lim_{\text{T}\to\infty}\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int_0^\text{T}\text{P}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\lim_{\text{T}\to\infty}\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int_0^\text{T}\text{U}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

Let us assume a few things to make life easier:

1. $$\text{R}=\text{C}=\text{L}=1\tag2$$
2. The input voltage looks like:
   $$\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\text{A}\cdot\sin\left(2\pi\cdot\text{f}\cdot t+\varphi\right)\tag3$$
   Where \$\text{A}=\text{f}=1\$ and \$\varphi=0\$.
3. For the initial conditons we have: \$\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(0\right)=0\$ and \$\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}'\left(0\right)=0\$.

So, we need to solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\text{A}\cdot\sin\left(2\pi\cdot\text{f}\cdot t+\varphi\right)\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}+\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}''\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}+\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\text{C}}\\
\\
\text{A}=\text{f}=\text{R}=\text{C}=\text{L}=1\\
\\
\varphi=0\\
\\
\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(0\right)=\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}'\left(0\right)=0
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

And when we solve that and using equation \$\left(1\right)\$, we find:

$$\overline{\text{P}}_{\space\text{in}}=\frac{2\pi^2}{1-4\pi^2+16\pi^4}\approx0.0129857\tag5$$

Answer (score 0):

Instantaneous power p(t) =v(t) *i(t)

By multiplying the instantaneous voltage and instantaneous current simply you will find the expression of instantaneous power.

Average power is the average of all the intantaneous values of power over the period of the waveform.

It can be found with the equation

Pave = Vrms *Irms *cos(theta)

Where theta is the angle of the current through the network or the angle of the impedence of the network.